# Looking for patterns for instantaneous data consistency for DB transactions that span multiple schemas in a Aurora postgres instance

Tags: database, aws, transaction

We are currently developing a product in the AWS environment that requires instantaneous data consistency for DB transactions that span multiple schemas in a Aurora postgres instance. Each schema will be updated by a service/micro-service/lambda orchestrated through step function workflow.

The only solution we came up with is to encapsulate all of the sql in a single transaction. That gets us to an all or nothing solution but it opens the question of how to do that. We came up with 2 patterns

connection shipping - send a connection object to each service that adds it's specific sql to the transaction and then it gets passed to the next service. Eventually it gets committed or rolled back.
sql shipping - each service generates sql (doesn't execute it) and passes it to an aggregator that collects all of the generated statements and when all the services have responded the aggregator begins a transaction that contains all of the generated sql under a single transaction.
Does anyone have experience with either of these patterns or another way to achieve instantaneous data consistency?

Comment: If you actually hard require instantaneous consistency, distributed services are probably the wrong way of building this.

Comment: Either those services need to be redesigned for eventual consistency, or they need to be combined. The "micro" in "micro service" doesn't mean services must be extremely small in size. They need to be independently deployable and scalable. Can you deploy these services independently?

Comment: Greg- yes they can be deployed independently and we’ve localized their individual functionality to specific domains. 

Instantaneous is an immutable business requirement so I’m trying to find other patterns that we have not thought of.

Comment: @JeffPrisco, I am starting to wonder if the stakeholder understands what they are asking for or if you maybe misunderstood what they want to have. As business requirements should be independent of the technology used, I would recommend you ask for clarifications and see how the requirement would work in a low-tech environment (business operates with pen and paper only; the employees doing the work are not a bottleneck).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Bart - it always amazes me how technology folks question business requirements they don't like. Business is not specifying a technology  - they're saying that at no time can domains of related data be out of synch. A database transaction that incorporates all of the domains involved is the solution we came up with. The ask is if anyone has experience with another pattern. Suggesting we try and convince the business their requirement is not important is kind of sidestepping the issue.